# How can I separate variables into an external asciidoc document?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm writing a book using asciidoctor. Documents look like this.

### book.asciidoc

```
:doctype: book
:icons: font
:source-highlighter: coderay

:apidocs-javase: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api
:apidocs-javaee: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api

include::chapter01.asciidoc[]
```

### chapter01.asciidoc

```
== Chapter 01 TITLE
....
{apidocs-javase}/java/io/InputStream.html#...
...
```

It renders fine and the result looks good.

Now I'm trying to use [Atom](https://atom.io/) along with [atom-asciidoc-preview](https://github.com/asciidoctor/atom-asciidoc-preview). The problem is that [atom-asciidoc-preview](https://github.com/asciidoctor/atom-asciidoc-preview) seems not capable to substitute variables properly.

I tries this.

### variables.asciidoc

```
:apidocs-javase: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api
:apidocs-javaee: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api
```

### chapter01.asciidoc

```
include::variables.asciidoc[]
== Chapter 01 TTILE
....
{apidocs-javase}/java/io/InputStream.html#...
...
```

I have no luck. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work, add a new line between the include and the header. It could also be that atom isn't handling it correctly.